# Why does zip() drop the values of my generator?

Tags: python

I was writing an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205037/detect-period-of-unknown-source) when noticed that my simple implementation didn't produce correct results. While hunting down the bug, I noticed the following:

```
In [1]: import itertools
In [2]: gen = itertools.cycle((0,1,2))

In [3]: zip(gen, range(3))
Out[3]: [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]

In [4]: zip(gen, range(3))
Out[4]: [(1, 0), (2, 1), (0, 2)]
```

For whatever reason, `gen`'s `next()` method is called one additioinal time.
To illustrate this, I used the following:

```
class loudCycle(itertools.cycle):
    def next(self):
        n = super(loudCycle, self).next()
        print n
        return n

In [6]: gen = loudCycle((0,1,2))
In [7]: zip(gen, range(3))
0
1
2
0
Out[7]: [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This happens because `zip` evaluates iterators [from left to right](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), meaning that, after three steps, it calls `next()` on `gen` and only then on `iter(range(3))` (or something like that) and encounters a `StopIteration`. To get around this, use the shorter (finite) iterable as the left-most argument:

```
In [8]: zip(range(3), gen)
0
1
2
Out[8]: [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 7):

[Your self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11210301/577088) is exactly right, and presents a very good solution -- *if* one of the arguments to `zip` is always shorter than the other. However, in situations where you don't know which will be shorter, you might find `islice` useful. `islice` also provides an easy workaround if you want the first item in your tuples to be from your generator. In your case, you could do this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> gen = itertools.cycle(('a', 'b', 'c'))
>>> seq = range(3)
>>> zip(itertools.islice(gen, len(seq)), seq)
[('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]
>>> zip(itertools.islice(gen, len(seq)), seq)
[('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]
```

Your answer is probably better in this case -- it's certainly simpler -- but I thought I'd add this as a supplement.