# Functional python -- why does only one of these generators require list() to work?

Tags: python, functional-programming, chinese-remainder-theorem

In computing the Chinese Remainder theorem from a vector of tuples (residue, modulus) the following code fails :

```
c = ((1,5),(3,7),(11,13),(19,23))

def crt(c):
        residues, moduli = zip(*c)
        N = product(moduli)
        complements = (N/ni for ni in moduli)
        scaled_residues = (product(pair) for pair in zip(residues,complements))
        inverses = (modular_inverse(*pair) for pair in zip(complements,moduli))
        si = (product(u) for u in zip(scaled_residues,inverses))
        result = sum(si) % N
        return result
```

Giving the result as **0** ( I guess the generated iterables are empty ). Yet the following code works perfectly :

```
def crt(c):
        residues, moduli = zip(*c)
        N = product(moduli)
        complements = list((N/ni for ni in moduli)) # <-- listed
        scaled_residues = (product(pair) for pair in zip(residues,complements))
        inverses = (modular_inverse(*pair) for pair in zip(complements,moduli))
        si = (product(u) for u in zip(scaled_residues,inverses))
        result = sum(si) % N
        return result
```

Which yields (a) correct result of **8851**.

Why should I have to `list(` one of the first generators? Adding `list` to any subsequent generator does not change the fail (0) result. Only listing this first generator produces the correct result. What is going on here ?

Comment: I like your questions about python!

Comment: Could this be the same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210300/why-does-zip-drop-the-values-of-my-generator

Comment: perhaps you could print `zip(residues,complements)` and then `zip(complements,moduli)` before iterating through?

Comment: @AlexL yes, the first zip using complements gives the correct list, but the second one is empty...since complements is exhausted by then. It makes sense that complements should be a list -- or just put a generator inside each call to zip that requires those complements.

Comment: I think it's better to write `[N/ni for ni in moduli]` instead `list((N/ni for ni in moduli))`

Comment: @DenisNikanorov I think so too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You iterate twice over `complements`. You can only iterate once over a generator expression.

If you are on Python 2.x, `zip(residues,complements)` will consume `complements` and there is nothing left for `zip(complements,moduli)`. On Python 3.x `zip` is a generator itself and the problem appears later in the code, when `sum()` actually runs the generators. It would pull two items from `complements` for each iteration.

Comment: Boom! That's it! I forgot that about generators. Is this **single use** quality of generators the same in other functional languages that have them...possibly Scala or Haskell?

Comment: by later in the code, what do you mean -- zip is also a generator?

Comment: I am guessing that this is why functional programming is called functional. If I broke up the above function into smaller functions instead of assigning generators to variables, the functions could call the generators when needed and there would be no exhaustion.

Answer (score 0):

For reference based on the suggestions in the answer I reimplemented the code in the question as follows:

```
def complements(moduli,N):
        return (N/ni for ni in moduli)

def scaled_residues(residues,complements):
        return (product(pair) for pair in zip(residues,complements))

def inverses(complements,moduli):
        return (modular_inverse(*pair) for pair in zip(complements,moduli))

def crt_residue_terms(scaled_residues,inverses):
        return (product(u) for u in zip(scaled_residues,inverses))

 def crt(c):   
    residues, moduli = zip(*c)
    N = product(moduli)
    return sum(
            crt_residue_terms(
                    scaled_residues(residues,complements(moduli,N)),
                    inverses(complements(moduli,N),moduli)
            )) % N
```

It now produces the correct result of **8851** without using any lists. Cool.

Comment: Note that contrary to popular belief, generator expressions are not always more efficient than lists. If you are iterating over small sets, often the memory trade-off is not worth.

Comment: @PauloScardine Noted. I believe you.